# Error con el query en MacOS

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave = $_POST["clave"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query( $conn ,"INSERT INTO registro (id, usuario, clave) VALUES(null, '$usuario', '$clave')")

if ($sql == true) {
  echo "User Successfully Added!";
} else {
  echo "User could not be added";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Cuando meto los datos en un `index.html` cuando le doy al botón enviar, me aparece el siguiente error :

Esta página no funciona localhost no puede procesar esta solicitud en este momento.

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Pero al momento de quitar la linea:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $conn ,"INSERT INTO registro (id, usuario, clave) VALUES(null, '$usuario', '$clave')");
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo agregar personas a mi base de datos sin errores en macOS 12.4?

Comment: Falta un punto y coma al final de la línea donde declaras `$result`.

Comment: Ya no falta el punto y coma :)

Comment: Hay varios errores de sintaxis ¿Dónde seleccionas la base de datos? Usa la forma: `new mysqli("el_server", "el_user", "su_passw", "la_BD");`. Por otro lado, ¿De dónde sale la variable `$sql` que usas en el último `if`?. Finalmente, no es un error como tal, pero si declaras `$conn` con `new ... ` es porque estás usando la forma orientada a objetos, entonces mantén ese estilo; o sea `result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ...");` Ver los [ejemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php).